# Imitating an item for xDB tracking from custom route/controller

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

I have some pages/items that uses client caching, so the requests to the server does not correlate to the actual visits of those pages at all. Therefore I cancel the current page interaction when those pages are rendered on the server. Instead I want to track the visits to those pages through a separate api route/controller. When I meet certain conditions, I'd like to track the request to the controller, as if it was a visit to the cached page/item. I've tried various approaches, but just can't get this to work. Any ideas of how this can be done properly?

Comment: The page Layout should not be cached tho? Where is your tracking code? Normally that would be on the page layout so that visits get tracked properly. Or are you using some kind of CDN to cache the entire output of the page?

Comment: So am I gathering correctly that you are looking to simulate a page visit via an AJAX call?

Comment: Exactly. The entire html page is cached in a CDN, so there are now real requests of the item layout/html at all on the server. On the page I do an ajax call, containing the item id etc, so in principle I have all the data in the api call to perform the tracking

Comment: Have you looked into [**FXM**](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager)?